# Sign in an Authenticated User from External SP with SAML SSO using ITfoxtec to the managed SP

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

My team is tasked with implementing SSO into our web application (full .net 4.8 hosted in Azure). However, we need to rely on authentication of an external application.

A bit of context. Imagine there are 2 separate companies (A and B) which have separate web apps (SP_A and SP_B). We are the company B in this context.

Here is the requested workflow:

1. A user of SP_A logs in SP_A. Authentication process is unknown to us.
2. This user wants to log in to SP_B without typing password and email (stored to authenticate them in SP_B).
3. They click on a button somewhere in SP_A and "magically" it signs them into our SP_B without any prompts.

We have accomplished that with [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction) nested in Authorization headers. Here is what happens behind the scenes:

1. A user presses the button in SP_A which makes a call to our REST API. Request has 2 parameters:
   a. API Key (we provide it to company A), b. Company Name
2. The API confirms that API key is assigned to a said company (A) and issues a JWT
3. JWT token is returned to the client and is included in the auth headers with all subsequent requests
4. The next request to our API contains user email and org name. API verifies that such user exists in our DB as well, authenticates and signs them into out SP_B web app.

Our client requested that we use SAML2.0 protocol instead.

I am using [ITfoxtec sample projects](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test) as a starting point, but I am quite lost.
All external articles want to enable one centralized IdP which would prompt a user for password and email once and Claims will be passed from IdP to SPs. It does not apply to our case, since users are auth-ed in SP_A app.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've also started today to look into this library. I'm not an expert in SAML, but why will you have to re-enter the user and password? In your application, you have to create a method, to request a "SAML request" to the IDP, and if the user is already logged in, it automatically will create a "SAML Assertion" to some endpoint that you have to create in order to validate it. Did you run the projects in git test folder? Run TestWebAppCore and TestIdpCore and install SAML tracer in the browser extension to see the SAMLs.

Answer (score 1):

if SP_A and SP_B are using the same IdP and both  implement SAML or OIDC SSO, then you are good.

The logic is like this: when user successfully logins to SP_A, the browser will get two sessions: one session for SP_A and one session for IdP.

When the user tries to login to SP_B, the browser will redirect the user to login to IdP, since IdP knows the user has already logged in, it will not prompt the login page. And then SP_B can also issue a session to this user.